# ImageMagick and spritesheet

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick

I'm working on a little script that generates a sprite sheet. I have 6 spritesheets and I need to re-organize them and put their content (once ordered) in a unique file.

I logically chose to use ImageMagick. But here I'm stuck.

Here is what I have so far :

```
 convert '%d.png[0-5]' \( -crop 456x912+0+0 -crop 3x6+0+0@ +append \) -append  test.png
```

This command line takes my 6 files (0.png to 5.png) crop them, and split them into 18 sprites. Once splited, the 18 sprites are aligned horizontally and then aligned vertically with the 18 previous one.

The problem is this command seems to only aligned them horizontally. Instead of being composed of 18x6 sprites, test.png is composed by 108x1 sprites.

Any idea how to perform this in one command ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try another imagemagick tool, "montage," for this one.

```
$ for i in `seq 1 18 `; do convert -background none -fill black -size 32x32 -pointsize 14 caption:"$i" $i.png; done

$ montage `ls ?.png` `ls ??.png` -tile 6x3 -geometry 32x32 tile.jpg
```

[image: the result]